# How does internal value type avoid box

Tags: c#

This is about Value Type box question.(Int32)

---

when I checked the IL codes, I found the IL call the Int32.ToString(),

and those nested method under Int32.ToString() are no box action,

as we know, if value type transform to references type, there is box,

and c# don't give us another way to process this transforming.

---

How does value type transform to references class(String)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling an instance method on a value-type, ***whenever possible*** it uses static-call or a "constrained" call; no box is needed unless the type doesn't implement a required method (requiring the `object` implementation). Why would it need a box? It just: doesn't create one because it doesn't need one.

Note: this is why you should **always** override all the methods when creating a value-type; if you don't override `ToString()` (for example), then it *will* need to create a box to call the virtual base method, but if you *do* override it, the compiler can just static-call the override, safe in the knowledge that the instance is never `null` and the method is never further overridden by a sub-type.

As a side note: the compiler may choose to emit "constrained" calls *in all cases* for value-types, which is essentially passing the handle to the JIT to say:

- if the target is a reference type, dereference and use virtual-call
- otherwise if the target is a value-type that implements the method, use static-call
- otherwise, dereference, box, and use virtual-call

However, in the case of inbuilt types (`int`, etc) it is more common to just go directly to the method via static-call. The reason for the "constrained" approach as a default is that it is safe to use even when somebody changes a library that declares the type (adding or removing implementations).

Comment: if I call Console.WriteLine("123456{0}",3.ToString()). How does value type 3 join in the reference type string. you say no box is ever needed, but how does the 3 on the stack frame move to string on the heap

Comment: @LuffyDing at no point does the value-type 3 move to the heap; the `ToString()` method creates a new completely unrelated object that *happens* to be a `string` and that happens to contain length 1 and unicode code-points with value 50 (which you might recognize as the character with appearance `'3'`) and probably a zero terminator, but that's got very little to do with the original value on the stack, other than that this is the value that it ran an "itoa"-style operation on

Comment: specifically, that is going to be `ldstr`, `ldc.i4.3`, `call` (int.ToString()), `call` (string.Format(string,string)), `call` (Console.WriteLine(string)) (give or take; it actually has to do a `stloc` / `ldloca` pair to do the `int.ToString` call)

Comment: The ToString() method creates a new completely unrelated object.  Is the "ToString()" process the box on the heap? as we know, the box also create a new completely unrelated object. My confused point is that how does the "ToString()" create the appearance "3"  on the heap

Comment: eg: string A = String.Format("I am {0}",3.ToString()); the A is on the heap. 3.ToString() without box create a object on the heap, and the String.Format combine the "I am" and "3" and return a address to A. the ToString() doesn't process box and return a String "3" on the heap, how does this happen?

Comment: When you call an instance method on a value type, the `this` parameter (aka `arg0`) is the address of the value-type itself. What happens is the `stloc`/`ldloca` pair: the constant value 3 is pushed to the stack (`ldc.i4.3`), and then stored in a local (`stloc.0`). The **address** of that local (not the value) is then pushed to the stack (`ldloca.s 0`). Now we use static-call (`call`) to invoke `Int32.ToString()`, which does what it needs, with the `this` being the value to run "itoa" on. Does that explain it?

Comment: Thank you so very much,This is the clearest answer I have got. and I hate the stack overflow's down vote, I think my question is very important. Thank you again.

Comment: @Luffy I think the downvote is because it is genuinely very unclear; but I can even things up a bit...

Comment: Thank you, I found you up vote me. I learn new English " I can even things up a bit".My teacher, you are great man.Haha